# Get current time in PHP and MySQL in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I work on project Android & PHP MySQL
now I have question in PHP file 
i want to get current time that user registered in application
so I will use " now()" in PHP file 
and datatype in db will be timestamp 
now my question in begin in file I use $_post[] 
and field date is this right or wrong to be in this form

```
$Username = $_POST['Username'];

$Date = $_POST['Date'];
```

and for my query

```
$Username = $_POST['Username'];

$Date = $_POST['Date'];



$Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO users (Username,Date) values ('$Username',NOW())";
```

is this right ? query and `$_POST['DATE']`
 or it should be `$date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');`
without post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need this line

```
$Date = $_POST['Date'];
```

just use `Now()` in your query , because it's a server value , if it will be a client value then the client will change and play on it easily

Comment: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    
    $Username = $_POST['Username'];
    
    
    
    $Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO users (Username,Date) values ('$Username',NOW())";
    
    
    
     if(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query))

Comment: welcome anytime ^^ , you can select my response as the correct answer , if everything is okay now

Answer (score 0):

U can use PHP date() function
insert:
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Comment: i want to use now(), so if i use now() i dont to define &_post[date], just write now in query?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the default value of the field `date` as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so you just need to run:

```
$Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO users (Username) values ('$Username')";
```

The date is going to be the current timestamp as default.